# MP android chart Line chart value spike form zero not correct

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart, linechart

I am playing around with mpchat and noticed this.[image]

I was streaming y value as 0 for some time and then a constant 68. Here you can see the first value change form 0 to 68 is not correct. How can i overcome this?